SciPy Stats Library .fit() Command Issues Generating Fit With Imported File
I have an Excel file I have imported into a Pandas DataFrame.  The file has four variables and we are supposed to run normality tests (Shapiro-Wilk, D'Agostino's, Anderson-Darling) for the data and then conduct goodness of fit tests.  The professor then had us run goodness of fit tests to determine what distribution best fits the data.  I was able to figure all of that information out.  But then he asks us to do this:
For each variable, develop a set of descriptive statistics and bar charts of the data.
With this step, the standard mean and variance equations from descriptive statistics are no good when the data are not normally distributed.
From the SciPy Stats library, look into the.fit() command.  As an example of using the command with exponentially distributed data, the command looks like this:
loc, scale = expon.fit(data)

Two objects, "loc" and "scale" will be returned and captured from the expon.fit() command
            """  Assignment 12 - Python 3 - Normality and GOF  """
                            """  Final Code  """

                            """  NORMALITY TESTS  """
                            
##  Upload libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import shapiro
from scipy.stats import normaltest
from scipy.stats import anderson
from statsmodels.graphics.gofplots import qqplot
from matplotlib import pyplot

##  Import data from Excel file
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\jbwor\OneDrive\Desktop\Assignment 12 - Normality and GOF Data.xlsx")
print(df)

##  Extract and test Variable_X1
data = df[["Variable_X1"]].to_numpy()
print(data)    

##  View the data with a histogram
pyplot.hist(data)
pyplot.show()

##  View the data with a QQ plot (a quartile plot)
qqplot(data, line='s')
pyplot.show() 

##  Statistical Test 1- Shapiro-Wilk
##  Capture two results at once: 'stat' and 'p'
##  'stat' will be the statistic
##  'p' will be the p value
stat, p = shapiro(data)

##  Print the stat, p = shapiro(data) command, rounding to three decimal places
print('Statistics=%.3f, p=%.3f'%(stat, p))

##  Interpret
##  We are going to make the program do the actual interpretation of the p-value
alpha = 0.05
if p > alpha:
    print('Based on Shapiro-Wilks, the sample looks Gaussian (fail to reject H0)')  
else:
    print('Based on Shapiro-Wilks, the sample does not look Gaussian (reject H0)') 

##  Statistical Test 2 – D’Agostino’s K^2 (from scipy.stats.normaltest)
##  We are going to capture two items again: 'stat' and 'p'
stat, p = normaltest(data)
print('Statistics=%.3f, p=%.3f'%(stat, p))

##  Interpret
alpha = 0.05
if p > alpha:
    print("Based on D'Agostino's K^2, the sample looks Gaussian (fail to reject H0)")  
else:
    print("Based on D'Agostino's K^2, the sample does not look Gaussian (reject H0)") 

##  Statistical Test 3 – Anderson-Darling

data = df["Variable_X1"].to_numpy()
result = anderson(data)
print(data)  
print('Anderson-Darling Statistic: %.3f' % result.statistic)
p=0
for i in range(len(result.critical_values)):
    sl,cv, = result.significance_level[i], result.critical_values[i]
    if result.statistic < result.critical_values[i]:
        print('%.3f: %.3f, Based on Anderson-Darling, the data looks normal (fail to reject H0)'% (sl,cv))
    else:    
        print('%.3f: %.3f, Based on Anderson-Darling, the data does not look normal (reject H0)'% (sl,cv))

So I have histograms of each variable, along with an associated QQ plot.  I have also described the statistics.  Since none of the variables were normally distributed, I listed the median, interquartile range, and skewness, which seem to be the "valuable" stats.  He's already given us the code to standardize the data, so I don't see a need to further analyze or explore any other descriptive statistics.
If he's asking us to fit the data to an exponential or beta distribution, I am not understanding how to do this.  Most of the examples I've seen online fit the data using randomly generated numbers, but I can't find any data where you fit the data using imported information.  If he's asking us to use the fit command to find the loc and scale, my understand is that's the mean and standard deviation, which again seems like overkill to me.  But if he's asking for us to fit the data and show it with a graph, I'm completely lost.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm sorry about the length of this post, but I'm new to this and I was hoping to give readers as much information I could for maximum help.
I've tried searching the SciPy Stats library, ChatGPT, and various other web sources, but it's giving me data to generate random numbers and THEN fit the data and I guess I'm slow or just having a hard time trying to visualize how to make it work with data I have imported into Python.

"If he's asking us to fit the data to an exponential or beta distribution": is he? Did you verify that with your professor? "descriptive statistics" could indeed simply be mean, median, variance, skew, kurtosis, percentiles and the like; that's my first thought. Doing an actual fit feels like a different thing. Since that paragraph says three times "if", you'd better check with the professor or fellow students if you're not going overboard.

Alternatively, of course you can do the fit. So do you want to do that anyway? Then you might want to give a [mcve], a simple example with some input data (i.e., not a path to a file, but an actual array) and your attempt at fitting that. Currently, your code contains a lot more than just the fit (e.g., all the plotting stuff), while the input file is not readable for us, so while people may be able to answer, we can give you a good example of your actual problem (fitting to e.g. exponential data). Do read up on what a [mcve] is; it helps us a lot answering your problem.

Thank you for your response. It's hard to tell what he wants, since it's only a 25 point assignment and he wants us to ask for help/research information before going to him. That information was given as a "PS" to the assignment and based on the fact that he's given me extra credit on other assignments for doing more than asked, I'm not going to worry about it too much.  I feel like he would have gone into how to develop the code in his video.  But at least this will give me a chance to show I researched the problem and had a solution.

"It's hard to tell what he wants" - but then you ask! If a problem is unclear, you ask further details about it to clear it up. You already know what's unclear, so that should be easy.

Note that you mention this, loc, scale = expon.fit(data), but I don't see any attempt in your actual code.
